# Customer import with duplicate email in Magento

Tags: magento

I have two huge CSV files containing customer data. I can import the first CSV file just fine (because there is no duplicate data). The problem is with the second CSV file. It contains some duplicate data from the first CSV. My question is, can Magento skip this duplicate data and import only the non-duplicate data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `magento skip the duplicate customer and import only non-duplicate` but magento doesn't give any error like skip customer or like that.

When you look at `class Mage_Customer_Model_Convert_Adapter_Customer` in  `saveRow($importData)` method and debug this you can easily understand how actually magento 
import customer